# IIS Express webapps don't show up in the system tray gui when I launch an asp.net core app from VS 2022 IDE

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I'm using Windows Server 2019 and would like to be able to stop or restart the app on iisexpress server from system tray gui in case there are any glitches, how can I restart the app with or without the system tray gui? I would prefer to just stop and restart the app not the entire server as I was able to do in the past using the system tray gui, but if anyone knows how to do this using bat script or using ps that could also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2019, you should host such web apps on full IIS and manage them via IIS Manager.

It makes no sense to use IIS Express, a non-production test server.

Comment: I'm not in production, just building templates I can post on github for my portfolio, but I have used full IIS manager in development as well as production before. Eventually I plan to set up my development environment using full IIS, but I would like a bit more information about this node server and how to configure so it run in tandem with IIS (how do I make this node server fire when I am debugging in VS in the absence of IIS Express?), which was completely absent in the other legacy versions of aspnet.

Comment: My understanding is that the node sever necessary in development for the interpretation of typscript (Angular language) into javascript when working in development. (ran out of characters in the other comment.)

Comment: @IjonTichy I wonder why you referred to "node server". But if indeed your question is more about development and Node.js, the question should be posted to Stack Overflow with more details what exactly is this web app and how Node.js is involved.

Comment: indeed, both my original and follow up question is more about configuration than coding. I am using Angular on the front-end, so as I said before the ts, in development needs to be interpreted to js, thats the only reason  the node server is involved, of course in production, I wouldn't need node.js, only the raw js output that's already been generated from the ts.